# Наклон арки в GDI+

Tags: windows, gdi, gdi+, graphics

Кто-нибудь знает, как в GDI+ задать направление арки?

P.S. В GDI это делается просто через вызов функции SetArcDirection.

Answer (score 1):

Семейство методов [DrawArc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535733(d=lightweight,v=VS.85).aspx) позволяет прямо указывать угол наклона арки.